# Protect circuit Schmitt Trigger

Tags: schmitt-trigger

This circuit is a protect circuit, and I search the google it seems like Schmitt Triger circuit,but I don't undertstand why should need the D1, and I don't know what's the function of D1.

Can someone help me to undertsantd this circuit.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Where did you find this circuit? Why didn't it come with an explanation? What do you mean when you say that it is a "protect circuit"?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I google it and it said it is a schmitt trigger usually to protect circut  when the Voltage is too high, and I know the schmitt trigger but I don't know when it add the D1 in this circut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diodes can be used in op-amp Schmitt Trigger circuits to adjust the upper and lower trigger points.

[image]

[Helpful REF](https://www.eeeguide.com/schmitt-trigger-circuit-diagram/)

Comment: Thanks your answer

But wht can adjust the R1 and R2 value (in your figure) to change the point. 

Can you show me math equation let me easy to understand plz

Comment: @Jitter456 Where did you get this circuit? Doesn't the source explain how to use it? This looks like it could be a homework/quiz question and we don't hand out solutions to those here.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It is not the homework/quiz this circuit is from my lab, but no one use it for a long time and I want to undertstand how it work, I google it but I don't find the answer so I come to here to help

Comment: @Jitter456 What is it used for in your lab? What is it connected to? Can you observe it working in the lab?

Comment: @Jitter456, check the reference link I provided. It goes through Schmitt Trigger design, how the circuit would react with no diode (with equations) vs how it reacts when you add a diode in one or both directions.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson it is a buck-boost converter's Peripheral, when the output voltage is too high the PWM will become low level. The circuit can't work so I need to fix and I need to understand the circuit's work.

Comment: @jmb2341 Thanks your help I will read it.